# OctoberCMS - calling PHP function wrriten in code segment in markup

Tags: php, content-management-system, octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-partial

Say I have a function in the code segment called "foo"

```
<?php

    function foo(){
        echo '<h1>hey</h1>';
    }
?>
```

I would like to call this function in the markup segment, something like `{{foo}}`.

How can I do that? I have tried doing exactly what I wrote, but it shows no result - a blank screen.

Comment: Have you tried calling it like a function? `{{foo()}}` What errors do you get, anything in the logs?

Comment: yes I tried , the error in this case would be "Unknown "foo" function".

Comment: can you share what you try to achieve we can help you! you can just define function and call-in code section and pass its output to markup and use it as variable

Comment: Ok, what I am trying to achieve is actually form handling.
say I have a form which on submit i want to use the function "foo".

and another form which on submit i want to use the function "foo2".

both forms are on the same page.
can you share a code example on how to do so on october CMS?

Comment: So you want to do an AJAX call, on your javascript/html part you can do a `$.request('onYourPhpFunction')`. You can see much informations here https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api

Comment: Thank you for this answer @SlevinKelevra , but this answer will work only with ajax handlers and not ``` 'onYourPhpFunction' ``` like you said, meaning I cant submit the form to a function called ``foo```

Comment: so just send the form to the same page, and in your onStart function, add your code to do what you want. 

I don't know exactly what your function is for, but, i think you can also create a markuptag for twig with your function inside a plugin.

Comment: yes I thought about doing that, @SlevinKelevra but wouldn't that be considered a "messy code" to handle multiple forms all in the same function?

Comment: Maybe send to the same page with a parameter different for all your forms, then in you onStart function, check that parameter, and call a function with respect to this parameter. 
Example: parameter == "foo" then call $this->foo(); or parameter == "bar" then call $this->bar();

Comment: Thanks you,  @SlevinKelevra , its a better way like you described, is there someone we can ask to check out if this is the "best" way to achieve this goal?